# Failing deployment AWS Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, flask, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-codepipeline

I am currently trying to build a CI/CD pipeline for my github repository, following this tutorial: https://aws.amazon.com/getting-started/hands-on/continuous-deployment-pipeline/

The only difference is instead of selecting PHP, I selected NodeJS as my platform(not sure if I'm doing it right).

The current repository I have has the following structure: (Flask backend + ReactJS frontend)

```
project
│   README.md
│       
│
└───client
│   │   src/ (contains app.tsx, pages etc...)
│   │   package.json
|   |.  package-lock.json
│   │
│   └───subfolder1
│       │   file111.txt
│       │   file112.txt
│       │   ...
│   
└───server
    │   app.py
    │   requirement.txt
```

I am getting the following error message: `Instance deployment failed to generate a 'Procfile' for Node.js. Provide one of these files: 'package.json', 'server.js', or 'app.js'. The deployment failed.`

The `package.json` file is nested inside my client folder. Or am I choosing the wrong platform?